# If Rome's women were the cause of her downfall, why did the Romans not import women from abroad?

Tags: roman-empire, women

The failing birthrate is named as one of the [contributing causes of the collapse of the western Roman empire](http://www.rhm.uni-koeln.de/128/Devine.pdf). However, in later, medieval times, all sorts of pirates, Vikings and others were involved in the supply of women, as the mortality rate of women was high then and there was a demand for them (obviously). Therefore, why did the Romans not import women from abroad or adopt legislative measures (like legalized polygamy, ...) to remedy the problem?

EDIT: To my fellow armchair historians. The falling birthrates in ancient times were caused mostly by deaths at childbirth. A good example of this would be Julius Caesar's daughter, Julia, who died in childbirth. It must have been so, as this problem persisted into the modern age. The baths idea is interesting but, IMO, not that relevant. It lists interesting sources, though, saying that there was a problem. Deaths, of course, created a need to replace women who died and women were being sold and bought all the way to the 19th century and, in some places, wives are sold and bought even today (Africa, Asia).

Comment: What's the similar situation today? What makes you assume that Romans didn't import women from abroad? What is the definition of "to import"?

Comment: The problem is **perhaps**. Your assumption is wrong if you think all the children born in Rome were legitimate (born out of lawful marriage) There must have been more bastards than legitimate children. That's my **assumption**. Also, you are **assuming** that Rome's political and census system would have been modern enough to pay attention to declining birth rate as we do today. Why do you think Romans were not involved in supplying of women like pirates, Vikings and others?

Comment: Speculative, bordering on counterfactual. History is about constructing a narrative around what _did_ happen; speculation about what might have happened if rulers had made alternate choices may be interesting, and it may even be instructional, but it is outside the mainstream of history.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "alternative" history is outside the scope of History.stackexchange.com

Comment: "also check the birth rate of your country, chances are it is falling. I think the fault lies largely with women today, perhaps it was the same in ancient times." This isn't a fault, it's progress.  The world is overpopulated and going back to having large families will only result in greater poverty, delinquency, crime, violence, and terrorism.  It's no coincidence that societies with large amounts of idle young men are violent places.  That's what you're advocating, which is a terrible idea unless you want to turn your country into the Gaza strip.

Comment: "Falling birth rate" does not mean "there's some problem with the women". I'm having trouble deciding if that attitude is offensive, or just ignorant.

Comment: Your edit is not logical. Women have always died in childbirth until modern medicine, but populations still rose. Various measures were taken to encourage Romans to reproduce - fining elderly bachelors, denying young widows inheritance rights if they did not marry, etc - but Romans seemed reluctant to shoulder the financial responsibility of large families. Are you suggesting there was a shortage of fertile aged women? If so, where's your evidence?

Comment: They still die in childbirth today. Perhaps not as much, but they still do. For evidence you need to look at some statistical data and extrapolate.

Comment: We need to be careful to distinguish death of the mother vs death of the child in childbirth. They are not always concurrent.

Comment: @called2voyage I did take it into account and it only reaffirms the suspicion that there was a problem with fertility in ancient Rome. Infant and child mortality was high and this could be offset only with higher fertility than would otherwise be necessary. This is the case, for example, in Africa, nowadays, where, despite the AIDS pandemic, the populations are steadily increasing. This is due to the incredible fertility rate down there.

Answer (score 6):

The paper that you linked to argues that fertility was low due to low sperm count arising from a fondness for too-hot baths.

The importation of women would not be expected to remedy a fertility problem originating on the male side.

Comment: Of course it could, the fault could not be assigned accurately then as now. That's why the harem was invented for the sultan's use later. The harem never failed to produce plenty of heirs. Also, the problem was spanning 5 centuries, perhaps more could be done?

Comment: Also, the paper might only be politically correct, but it quotes sources that confirm the problem was present in ancient Rome for almost 600 years.

Comment: @user1095108 *I tried shooting at one target a hundred times and never hit it, so I bought 5 targets and shot at each a hundred times. I hit 3 a few times. Obviously the problem is with the targets.* What is wrong with this picture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46371/discussion-between-t-e-d-and-called2voyage).